# Smali - Undeclared static method

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, smali

After compiling a certain apk and going through the smali code I stumbled upon this line in file com/name/name/r.smali:

```
invoke-static {v1, v0, v2}, Lcom/name/name/p;->a(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/List;Lcom/name/name/CallbackI;)V
```

> name is a placeholder in this situation

Unfortunately both of the classes p and CallbackI don't exist in com/name/name, how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

1. The code referencing those missing classes is dead code that never gets executed.
2. The app crashes when it tries to run that code.
3. The classes are defined elsewhere. Is the app using multi-dex? Or maybe the app uses a DexClassLoader to load another dex file?

Comment: what do you mean by multi-dex?

Comment: Multidex is where an app has multiple dex files. classes.dex, classes2.dex, etc. (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) By default baksmali only disassembles classes.dex. You can use the -e parameter to specify a different dex file within the apk to disassemble. e.g. `baksmali test.apk -e classes2.dex`